# Testes e2e do protractor roda com sucesso no local mas apresenta erro na pipeline do Azure

Tags: angular, e2e

No meu local, quando rodo o comando `npm run e2e` ele roda o teste normal e executa com sucesso o script:

```
"e2e": "concurrently \"webdriver-manager start --standalone\" \"ng e2e\""
```

Porem, na pipeline do azure, que roda o mesmo comando, apresenta erro 199:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não encontrei informações referentes a esse erro code 199.

Versões usadas:

```
"@angular/core": "~10.0.14",
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
"webdriver-manager": "^12.1.8",
"concurrently": "^5.3.0",
```